# Grammar corrections: Good or Bad

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I asked a question and it had a lot of grammatical mistakes. I'm glad someone notified me, and that was a good thing. But when I saw all the red, I was wondering if it could have bad consequences, such as reducing my reputation, which is a bad thing.

Comment: Someone editing your question is nothing bad- At least in the case of fixing grammar. The red you saw was the differences between your original post, and what the editor change which was in green. Nothing bad at all. In fact, editing is encouraged for grammar and spelling fixes, or even just helping a non-native English speaker make their point clear and concise.

Comment: [This page in the help center,](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) though it does not directly answer your question, explains a bit more about editing and how it works. If you haven't taken a look at it yet, you should go check it out and see what else you can learn on the subject. :)

Comment: Apart from grammar and spelling corrections, editors may also restructure your question; for example, to point out the actual question, or add or remove tags. It's quite useful to compare your original against the edits, as it will teach you the preferred format for SO questions.

Comment: Fixing grammar and typos are a good thing. Editing helps improve readability of the post. However, as the original author, you receive a red notification, so that you can review the changes and rollback (if required).

Comment: @call-me Don't worry about your question being edited. See Kendra's first comment. Also, a poorly-written question, comment or answer will have consequences, so make sure you make an effort to write as best as you can. Not only does it help prevent headaches and saw eyes, it also helps us help you much quicker. :-)

Comment: I've had one question edited to change my spellings to American English, put full-stops I had after quotes inside the quotations and change my quotes to curly quotes. He made some helpful edits and answered my question too but I changed back the spellings and put the full-stops back outside the quotations where they belong. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: @PeadarÓDuinnín there is a minimum change per edit -about 6 or 8 characters. When the editor's 'main' change is too small, usually they will look for minor things to tinker with to reach the threshold. Curly quotes, moving full-stops, is the kind of thing that happens, since it's clearly not going to change the meaning. I'm not confident this is what happened in your case, but it's something to bear in mind.

Comment: Yes, there are people who think American English is the only acceptable language here.  It would be interesting to have an official position from the Stack Overflow team about the acceptability of other versions of English.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Yes, bad grammar == bad consequences.

Poor grammar makes your question difficult to read and understand.  In addition, it makes it look as if you put very little effort into writing your question.  Regardless of whether or not this is true, it is what people will generally think.

So, people may very well downvote the post for being unclear or sloppy.  Some may even vote to close the question as "Unclear what you are asking".  This may not happen to *every* post with bad grammar, but I have seen it dozens of times.

Fortunately, most +2k rep users are willing to edit out bad grammar and make the post clear and readable.  If you have a hard time with grammar or are not fluent in English, I would recommend that you leave a comment on the question which says this and kindly asks them to fix the wording.  Do not put this in the question however because it will most likely be treated as noise.

Comment: I disagree with your first line. You don't get any *bad* consequences for having bad grammar -- frankly, if this is happening, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @hichris123 What do you mean? You don't think there are bad consequences that arise from poor grammar? Grammar and readability greatly affect how easy or difficult a question is to understand, so I would say you're wrong.

Comment: @TylerH Of course there are some consequences (such as less readability), but you're not going to be question banned for using bad grammar. Bad consequences is misleading to me: it sounds like if you can't use perfect grammar, don't post a question (to me, at least).

Comment: @hichris123 You won't be banned by the system, but fewer people will consider answering the question because they find it hard to read/understand. Some people may even downvote you for a poorly-worded question. Both of those are bad consequences. This is not to say I disagree with you completely; I think grammar corrections are good, and one should proofread/spell check before posting, but I don't think users should be downvoted for it. Instead of downvoting, users should VTC - Unclear or--preferably--edit the post to improve it.

Comment: @TylerH For some users, English is their second language. We simply cannot expect them to use perfect grammar -- heck, I'm a native speaker, and I don't use perfect grammar all the time! I'm simply saying the word "bad" seems to be an overstatement. If you only have a few grammatical errors, I don't think anyone will care, as long as it isn't getting to the "I have no idea what you're saying..." stage.

Comment: @simonzack You can always comment on your own posts.

Comment: @hichris123: I dunno, generally if you suck at writing questions then you'll get banned pretty quickly, and poor grammar is the #1 sign of that regardless of whether you intended it to be that way. And if someone isn't a native speaker, what can we do about it if their English skills are just so bad that we *cannot understand them* no matter how hard we try? It's unfortunate, but that's just how it is.

Comment: @BoltClock For the vast majority of users, sure. Seems like the OP isn't this vast majority though. If you can state your ideas clearly but have bad grammar, you should be fine. But yeah, most users who use bad grammar *and* don't make much sense get question banned.

Comment: I think I can see the difference between being sloppy or being not very good at English. In the first case, I will downvote in the second case I probably won't, although I usually don't think it's necessary to correct every mistake.

Comment: well... if the grammar is THAT bad, so it's unclear what the question is about (possibly leading to downvotes), editing the grammar might lead to a question that was never meant this way?!?

Comment: I think the user is specifically asking if the grammar corrections directly led to bad consequences (ie, if there is a direct penalty for needing to be edited).

Comment: @Micka If it's so bad that nobody can understand it, that's probably true. But there's a range of "badness" that makes a question difficult to read, and may cause some people to downvote, but is still clear enough to be rescued by somebody who puts the effort into it. Also, some people will be more skilled at deciphering poor English that may not make any sense to others.

Answer (score 22):

There will not be any major consequences due to not using perfect grammar, no. It's understood that some users may not know English as their first language, so people take this into account. You may get a downvote on your question or a close vote for "Unclear what you're asking", but this would only be if someone can't understand what you're saying -- usually there are more major issues than simple grammatical errors.

There are some suggestions in [What’s the best way to ask a question if English isn't your first language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/what-s-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language) for English as a Second Language users, such as:

> Nobody seems to have mentioned - Quote this at the end of each
>   question or answer you ask (in italics):
>
> *"English is not my first language, please edit for clarity, then
>   remove this comment!"*

(I might recommend placing this as a comment underneath the question, but it's up to you.)

In addition, another user answered:

> English is my third language. Here are some solutions:
>
> - Read a lot of questions, this will give you an insight of how 'we ask'
> - Read replies, so you can understand your future answers
>
> If you read a lot, you'll be able to write your own questions, here is
>   some advice:
>
> - Have a simple but descriptive title.
> - Explain *clearly* what your problem is. Including code or a screenshot is useful, try to explain what you want to do and how you
>     want it.
> - Include the language, the version, and the OS platform.
> - Don't use 'chat' language.
>
> Hope those tips help get you started!

All in all, don't feel ashamed if you're an ESL user and can't understand all the grammatical nuances. English is a difficult language. Stack Exchange users are very understanding, and only get annoyed if someone clearly understands how to speak and write English, but is simply being lazy. Simply **state your problem as clearly as possible** and **make sure to look at your question/answer before posting, and ask yourself, "If I was someone else, would I understand what I'm asking/saying?"**

Comment: Definitely put it in a comment. We can always flag it as "obsolete" later.

Comment: Strongly second "All in all, don't feel ashamed if you're an ESL user and can't understand all the grammatical nuances. English is a difficult language. Stack Exchange users are very understanding, and only get annoyed if someone clearly understands how to speak and write English, but is simply being lazy."

Comment: Please don't add things to the question that aren't actually part of the question.  If you want to apologise for your English, or to ask for grammatical corrections, please do it in a comment.

Comment: Ironically, I don't understand some of the quoted advice. "including code or screen shot is not useful". Really? I think that including code can be very useful for many questions.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I'm fairly certain that the author didn't mean that. I'll edit both posts accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

The red in post diffs just highlights removed words; it does not indicate that any sort of punishment shall ever be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

In general, whenever absolutely anything on StackOverflow changes your reputation, you'll get a notification at the top of the screen:

[image]

(Image from this question: [Top-bar notifications are not updating (a) after I view them and (b) to reflect new changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238158/top-bar-notifications-are-not-updating-a-after-i-view-them-and-b-to-reflect))

If you lost reputation after someone edited your post to fix the notifications, you'd have been notified. (Fortunately, you'll never use reputation as a direct result of someone editing one of your posts, regardless of why they did so.) And anytime anything affects your reputation one way or another going forward, you'll be able to know what caused the change.

Comment: Welcome to the site, by the way! I hope you learn a lot from us, find ways to be helpful and have fun, and earn lots of reputation ;-)